# iPhone thinks all videos in e.target.files are image/jpeg. All other platforms are fine

Tags: reactjs, iphone, input, upload

In my react application I was experiencing a bug where users on iPhone trying to upload videos to the platform were unsuccessful.

On my Windows Desktop, Android Devices, and family iPad there are no issues so I tried to do some troubleshooting.

This is my 'handleMedia' function for the Input element as well as the input element for reference:

```
<input
              hidden
              multiple
              accept="video/mp4,video/avi,video/quicktime,video/x-ms-wmv,image/*"
              style={{ display: "none" }}
              id="raised-button-file"
              type="file"
              onChange={handleMedia}
            />
```

and

```
  const handleMedia = (e) => {
    const files = e.target.files;
  
    const allowedVideoExtensions = ["mp4", "avi", "mov", "wmv"];
  
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      const file = files[i];
      const fileExtension = file.name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
  
      const isVideo = allowedVideoExtensions.includes(fileExtension);
      const isImage = !isVideo; // Consider it an image if it's not a video
        
      // console.log("File Name:", file.name, "Extension:", fileExtension, "Is Video:", allowedVideoExtensions.includes(fileExtension));
      alert(`File Name: ${file.name}, Extension: ${fileExtension}, Is Video: ${isVideo}, fileType: ${file.type}, fileSize: ${file.size / 1024 / 1024}`);
  
      if (isImage && file.size > 20 * 1024 * 1024) { // 20 MB
        alert("One or more of your images exceed the 20MB size limit. Please select smaller files.");
        return;
      } else if (isVideo && file.size > 200 * 1024 * 1024) { // 200 MB
        alert("One or more of your videos exceed the 200MB size limit. Please select smaller files.");
        return;
      }
    }
  
    setMedia(Array.from(e.target.files));
  };
```

So these values are all what you would expect on the other platforms, but on iPhone I select files I know the extensions of, which I know are videos, and I get a file.name ending in .jpeg instead of what it should be (mp4 or mov for example), a fileType of image/jpeg, and a fileSize that matches the movie file.

What the heck is going on here?

Edit: I stripped down the input to more easily test this on devices the problem persists, below

```html
import React from "react";
import { Flexbox, FlexboxCol, Typo } from "../../UI/StyledComponents";
import CameraAltIcon from "@mui/icons-material/CameraAlt";

const TestComponent = () => {
  const handleMedia = (e) => {
    const files = e.target.files;
    const allowedVideoExtensions = ["mp4", "avi", "mov", "wmv"];

    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      const file = files[i];
      const fileExtension = file.name.split(".").pop().toLowerCase();

      const isVideo = allowedVideoExtensions.includes(fileExtension);
      const isImage = !isVideo; // Consider it an image if it's not a video

      alert(
        `File Name: ${
          file.name
        }, Extension: ${fileExtension}, Is Video: ${isVideo}, fileType: ${
          file.type
        }, fileSize: ${(file.size / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2)}MB`
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <FlexboxCol fWidth fHeight withScrollbar hideScroll fullPadding={24}>
      <FlexboxCol fWidth fullPadding={8} sx={{ border: "1px solid #00ace8" }}>
       <Typo sx={{ fontSize: ".75rem", color: '#fff', backgroundColor: '#000', direction: 'ltr', whiteSpace: "pre-wrap", }}>
          accept="video/mp4,video/avi,video/quicktime,video/x-ms-wmv,image/*"
        </Typo>
        <Flexbox fWidth>
          <input
            hidden
            multiple
            accept="video/mp4,video/avi,video/quicktime,video/x-ms-wmv,image/*"
            style={{ display: "none" }}
            id="raised-button-file"
            type="file"
            onChange={handleMedia}
          />
          <label htmlFor="raised-button-file" style={{ height: 28, width: 28 }}>
            <CameraAltIcon
              sx={{ mx: 0.4 }}
              style={{ color: "#00ace880", height: 28, width: 28 }}
            />
          </label>
        </Flexbox>
      </FlexboxCol>
      <FlexboxCol fWidth fullPadding={8} sx={{ border: "1px solid #00ace8" }}>
       <Typo sx={{ fontSize: ".75rem", color: '#fff', backgroundColor: '#000', direction: 'ltr', whiteSpace: "pre-wrap", }}>accept="video/*,image/*"</Typo>
        <Flexbox fWidth>
          <input
            hidden
            multiple
            accept="video/*,image/*"
            style={{ display: "none" }}
            id="raised-button-file"
            type="file"
            onChange={handleMedia}
          />
          <label htmlFor="raised-button-file" style={{ height: 28, width: 28 }}>
            <CameraAltIcon
              sx={{ mx: 0.4 }}
              style={{ color: "#FF5733", height: 28, width: 28 }}
            />
          </label>
        </Flexbox>
      </FlexboxCol>

      <FlexboxCol fWidth fullPadding={8} sx={{ border: "1px solid #00ace8" }}>
       <Typo sx={{ fontSize: ".75rem", color: '#fff', backgroundColor: '#000', direction: 'ltr', whiteSpace: "pre-wrap", }}>accept="video/*"</Typo>
        <Flexbox fWidth>
          <input
            hidden
            multiple
            accept="video/*"
            style={{ display: "none" }}
            id="raised-button-file"
            type="file"
            onChange={handleMedia}
          />
          <label htmlFor="raised-button-file" style={{ height: 28, width: 28 }}>
            <CameraAltIcon
              sx={{ mx: 0.4 }}
              style={{ color: "#33FFBD", height: 28, width: 28 }}
            />
          </label>
        </Flexbox>
      </FlexboxCol>

      <FlexboxCol fWidth fullPadding={8} sx={{ border: "1px solid #00ace8" }}>
        <Typo sx={{ fontSize: ".75rem", color: '#fff', backgroundColor: '#000', direction: 'ltr', whiteSpace: "pre-wrap", }}>
          accept="video/mp4,video/x-m4v,video/*"
        </Typo>
        <Flexbox fWidth>
          <input
            hidden
            multiple
            accept="video/mp4,video/x-m4v,video/*"
            style={{ display: "none" }}
            id="raised-button-file"
            type="file"
            onChange={handleMedia}
          />
          <label htmlFor="raised-button-file" style={{ height: 28, width: 28 }}>
            <CameraAltIcon
              sx={{ mx: 0.4 }}
              style={{ color: "#9037af", height: 28, width: 28 }}
            />
          </label>
        </Flexbox>
      </FlexboxCol>
    </FlexboxCol>
  );
};

export default TestComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the video being uploaded isn't in the format you're expecting.
Your code is stating that if the file isn't one of `allowedVideoExtensions`, then it *must* be an image.

You could do something like the below, where you check the allowed image extensions in the same way that you check the allowed video extensions:

```js
  // these can be defined at the top of the file and not in the function
  const allowedVideoExtensions = ["mp4", "avi", "mov", "wmv"];
  const allowedImageExtensions = [ ... ]


  const handleMedia = (e) => {
    const files = e.target.files;
 
  
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      const file = files[i];
      const fileExtension = file.name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
  
      const isVideo = allowedVideoExtensions.includes(fileExtension);
      const isImage = !isVideo && allowedImageExtensions.includes(fileExtension); // Consider it an image if it's not a video
        
      // console.log("File Name:", file.name, "Extension:", fileExtension, "Is Video:", allowedVideoExtensions.includes(fileExtension));
      alert(`File Name: ${file.name}, Extension: ${fileExtension}, Is Video: ${isVideo}, fileType: ${file.type}, fileSize: ${file.size / 1024 / 1024}`);
  
      if (isImage && file.size > 20 * 1024 * 1024) { // 20 MB
        alert("One or more of your images exceed the 20MB size limit. Please select smaller files.");
        return;
      } else if (isVideo && file.size > 200 * 1024 * 1024) { // 200 MB
        alert("One or more of your videos exceed the 200MB size limit. Please select smaller files.");
        return;
      }
    }
  
    setMedia(Array.from(e.target.files));
  };
```

But, depending on what is available in the data, it may be possible to (inside the loop) do this:

```js
      const file = files[i];
      const fileType = file.type; // this will give you the MIME-type

  
      const isVideo = fileType.includes("video/");
      const isImage = fileType.includes("image/");
```

That way you should be able to access the [file MIME-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_API/Using_files_from_web_applications#type) instead, which you could then see if it contains `"image/"` or `"video/"` which would reduce the overhead and free up the extension checking

Comment: This is the confusing part. The alert as you can see displays what the application thinks the file.type and fileExtension are -- and whenever I select video files it always says the file.type is image/jpeg and fileExtension is .jpeg when I know in fact the files I've selected are not images. Keep in mind this same alert on all other platforms displays the proper file.type and fileExtension with the exact same files.

Comment: In addition, I must point out that this behavior is from selecting 'Photo Library' when clicking on the input element. If I select 'Choose File(s)' instead and select a video or videos then the issue does not occur and everything works. I know my users will be selecting from their Photo Library however, as would be expected.

Comment: Oh I see, I'll have a think and I'll update my answer, do you have a CodePen I could test the issue with?

Comment: I have also asked other users experiencing the same problem to share screenshots and I included these two for you (one from me, and one from her). https://files.catbox.moe/eb8c8b.png and https://files.catbox.moe/0x0gqn.jpeg

Comment: I don't think a stripped down test environment will do I/we can't change the code like in a CodePen, I also can't see a form element on that link either so not all data may be being captured correctly

Comment: Hi Harrison -- I was about to put a codepen together when I thought I would try w3 schools example which is entirely stripped down in a way anyone can replicate: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_file and even this input is identifying my videos as jpegs. I am now suspecting that some iPhones are storing all or most videos as HEIC or HEVC files which the phone converts to JPEG before uploading.